# Error: no integrated GPU detected

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I have a legion 5 15ach6h laptop, installed with dual boot win7/ubuntu 22.04
My system has two GPUs (Ryzen 5600H integrated gpu and nvidia one), i'm not gaming on linux so i don't want to use the Nvidia GPU which is apparently activated by default.

First off, i don't have the PROIME PROFILES tab in the nvidia-settings app
i tried to switch to the integrated GPU via the CLI but couldn't do it.

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

gives me this error message: Error: no integrated GPU detected.

i'm using the nvidia 515 driver because the 525 only display 2 tabs and still no prime profiles tab and it also causes a black screen upon suspending my PC.

what can i do to use the integrated gpu ?